# Hiding Navigation bar on android API16

Tags: java, android

I am developing an application and need to hide the navigation bar permanently. What I found is just to hide it and when the screen touch happens it will pop up again. I am using Android API16. I tried the following but didnt help.

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Comment: Please any help for this? I still can't find the solution.

Comment: Ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

try this, and let me know if it works for you:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
        }else {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. I use it and gives the same result. It will hide the bar and once I touch the screen  the navigation bar appears again